# Adding % sign to a R Plot

Tags: r, text, plot, expression

I want to add a number and % sign to a plot. For instance, I want the north-east quadrant to say 24.7%, instead of 24.7. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a minimum working example:

```
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2)   
Coefsim = rmvnorm(1000, c(0, 0), Sigma )
NE = sum( Coefsim[,1] > 0 & Coefsim[,2] > 0 )/10
NW = sum( Coefsim[,1] < 0 & Coefsim[,2] > 0 )/10
SE = sum( Coefsim[,1] > 0 & Coefsim[,2] < 0 )/10
SW = sum( Coefsim[,1] < 0 & Coefsim[,2] < 0 )/10


plot(Coefsim[,1],Coefsim[,2], pch = 16, cex = .4, xlab = expression(hat(beta)),  ylab = expression(hat(phi)), las=1)
abline(a=NULL, b=NULL, h=0, v=0,col=c("red", "red"))
text(2.5, 2.5, NE)
text(2.5, -2.5, SE)
text(-2.5, 2.5, SW)
text(-2.5, -2.5, NW)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can transform the values before adding them to the plot:

```
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2)   
Coefsim = rmvnorm(1000, c(0, 0), Sigma )
NE = sum( Coefsim[,1] > 0 & Coefsim[,2] > 0 )/10
NW = sum( Coefsim[,1] < 0 & Coefsim[,2] > 0 )/10
SE = sum( Coefsim[,1] > 0 & Coefsim[,2] < 0 )/10
SW = sum( Coefsim[,1] < 0 & Coefsim[,2] < 0 )/10

NE <- c(as.character(NE), "%")
NE <- paste0(NE, collapse = "")

NW <- c(as.character(NW), "%")
NW <- paste0(NW, collapse = "")

SE <- c(as.character(SE), "%")
SE <- paste0(SE, collapse = "")

SW <- c(as.character(SW), "%")
SW <- paste0(SW, collapse = "")


plot(Coefsim[,1],Coefsim[,2], pch = 16, cex = .4, xlab = 
expression(hat(beta)),  ylab = expression(hat(phi)), las=1)
abline(a=NULL, b=NULL, h=0, v=0,col=c("red", "red"))
text(2.5, 2.5, c(NE))
text(2.5, -2.5, SE)
text(-2.5, 2.5, SW)
text(-2.5, -2.5, NW)
```